# Windows Phone 8.1 Emulator in Windows 10

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-10, windows-phone-emulator

I can't install the windows phone 8.1 emulator on my VS2015 in Windows 10. VS tells me that I need Windows 8.1 with Hyper-V.

Is it possible to install Windows Phone 8.1 Emulator in Visual Studio 2015 in Windows 10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Turn on virtualization on your bios settings, so you can enable Hyper-V.

Check this tutorial.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj863509(v=vs.105).aspx

I had no problem installing it on the same setup as you.

Comment: Hyper-V is not BIOS option, it's system component. In BIOS you can only enable virtualization (required by Hyper-V)